# What type of floor drain is this and can I connect pipes to it?

Tags: plumbing, drain, plumbing-fixture

Everything is fine with the drain, however there was some gunk left on this picture because no one used it for years and I was cleaning it up when I took the picture, here is my floor drain which was closed off with a cap:

[image]

I can't see what exactly happens, but first off this black plastic is not removable - it might be stuck with concrete in the floor. Anyways, the whole idea with this drain is that it's not going straight down to the sewer. First there is water that is always stuck in the larger basin, which drains into the smaller hole which ends up to a flat surface with a small circular 360* open, which then it might (I suppose) continue to the normal pipe, I draw a section view what I think happens here:

[image]

So what type of drain floor is this and can I connect bathtub drain pipes to it (although it is already narrow, short and I cannot use reducer).

Comment: It looks to me like an adapter to hold a nice drain pipe, the drain is larger than the pipe and recessed in the nice tile floor. And it's probably just plugged with a cap. It's a shower drain, and therefore should be ok for a bathtub.  I'm not an expert in this area and someone would need to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
It is not made for more pipes, it is a floor drain and the only way to hook more pipes t it is to break up the floor and tie into 3" line that drain does eventually tie into.

This picture of the drain cap I was referring t. It is like the older cast iron type. Looking up this type of drain that is around now have openings all over it.

[image]
 The way it is supposed to work is, the water is not supposed to go directly into the drain in the center. It fills the "cup" around the perimeter, catching any objects that get washed in by the flow of water. The objects will settle in the bottom of the catch basin and the water will fill up enough to pour over the edge and go down the waste pipe in the center.

Comment: Part 1: Thank you for the very thorough answer, everything makes perfect sense. It seems like I am missing this part that you've linked and I only have a stainless steel cover with holes everywhere. I also drawn above how this narrower drain ends, which is not into a pipe but a flat piece that circularly drains which use is probably also made to hold larger debris. For what you are saying that the way I can do it, is to break up the floor (probably alluding to this floor drain), however is there a way I can mitigate this and maybe put something narrower or wider?

Comment: Part 2: This drain for some reason is placed against gravity, so when I run my shower - the water flows in different direction. So I bought like a shower section which I would like to install - here is a picture: https://i.imgur.com/JHBAn33.png so I would like to find a solution to drain it into this floor drain. I was also not sure if I need a p-trap or not, there was no smell ever - but it might be gunk build up blocking. This was a newly build part, build some time ago and it is raised above the other floors for about 6 inches for the pipes, but I know that it doesn't mean a p-trap exists.

Comment: The drawing would need some details added to it depicting what the radiating blue lines mean and other parts you have drawn. For example, is the blue oval the top of the water level in the larger pipe?

Comment: You will most certainly need to add more pictures. For I do not know what you mean by the drain "is placed against gravity". Also how is it " raised above the other floors for about 6 inches for the pipes" A picture showing that, will help understand what you are trying to do. I think I do, but I don't want to go in the wrong direction.

Comment: Tell me if I am correct Or at least how close am I.. The existing floor of the proposed shower area is raised 6" higher than the surrounding floors outside the area you wish to use for the shower. You wish to break out the old drain in the corner, or near the corner and reconfigure it so the corner drain of the new shower pan will line up and connect to the pipe in the floor.

Comment: So this bathroom is connected to a bedroom, the floor of the bathroom is 6 inches higher than the floor of the bedroom as they did this for pipe installation. In perfect setting, I wouldn't want to break anything. This floor drain is placed on the side and the water doesn't go into it, it just flows past it, that is what I mean by gravity. I realized that this is a floor drain, probably something like a nanhi trap because water always stays in the small hole, so I cannot really remove this: https://i.imgur.com/63AtvWY.png. If I could somehow fit a pipe around or in, that is my preferre outcome

Comment: I continue this here as it is going off-topic: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/187185/how-would-i-go-connecting-this-drain-to-a-pipe So please feel free to reply there.